# How to add FFMPEG GPU Logo

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, gpu, wowza-transcoder

I just couldn't do it. Is the problem with the Filter?

This is the command I am trying to run:

`ffmpeg -hwaccel_device 1 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -f concat -safe 0 -stream_loop -1 -i /media/mylist.txt -i /logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=main_w*0.01:y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01)" -c:a aac -c:v h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast -tune hq -r 25 -b:v 3M -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mystream`

This is the output I am getting:

```
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/logo.png':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 130x66 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 65:33], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Codec AVOption tune (The metric that the encoder tunes for. Automatically chosen by the encoder by default) specified for output
file #0 (rtmp://127.0.0.1:25462/live/mystream) has not been used for
any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video
option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some
encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay (graph 0)
Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay (graph 0)
overlay:default (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (h264_nvenc)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
[aac @ 0x562ac3287f80] Qavg: 481.281
[aac @ 0x562ac3287f80] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Note that SO is only about programming questions. You could ask your question at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) which is for general problems with computer hardware and software. Also it seems that you haven't taken any attempts to solve the problem by yourself, or haven't included them in your question. Please edit your question including the attempts and research you've done.

Comment: my english is a little bad

Comment: You likely need to use `overlay_cuda` filter instead. You may also need to use `hwupload` to upload the PNG data to GPU memory (or see if you can use `-hwaccel` option for the PNG input.

Comment: How can I do Syntax? Can you help